# Sum a column and perform more calculations on the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my query below I am counting occurrences in a table based on the `Status` column. I also want to perform calculations based on the counts I am returning. For example, let's say I want to add 100 to the `Snoozed` value... how do I do this? Below is what I thought would do it:

```
SELECT 
    pu.ID Id, pu.Name Name,
    COUNT(*) LeadCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Working' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Working,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Uninterested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Uninterested,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Converted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Converted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Snoozed,
    Snoozed + 100 AS Test
FROM
    Prospects p
INNER JOIN 
    ProspectsUsers pu on p.OwnerId = pu.SalesForceId
WHERE 
    p.Store = '108'
GROUP BY 
    pu.Name, pu.Id
ORDER BY 
    Name
```

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Snoozed'.

How can I take the value of the previous SUM statement, add 100 to it, and return it as another column? What I was aiming for is an additional column labeled Test that has the Snooze count + 100.

Comment: The error is clear, do this:`100 + SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Test`

Comment: `Snoozed` is an alias, not a column name. You can't use it, so instead of `Snoozed + 100 AS Test` use `SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 100 AS Test`

Comment: The accepted answer of the question this is flagged a duplicate of does not contain valid SQL server syntax. @TabAlleman

Comment: @Cowthulhu oops, I used a MySQL duplicate.   I have corrected it to point to a TSQL duplicate.

Comment: @TabAlleman Rock on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL does not allow you to reference fields (or aliases) in the SELECT statement from within the same SELECT statement.

To work around this:

1. [Use a CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Define the columns you want to select from in the CTE, and then select from them outside the CTE.

```
;WITH OurCte AS (
SELECT
    5 + 5 - 3 AS OurInitialValue
)

SELECT
    OurInitialValue / 2 AS OurFinalValue
FROM OurCte
```

2. Use a temp table. This is very similar in functionality to using a CTE, however, it does have different performance implications.

```
SELECT
    5 + 5 - 3 AS OurInitialValue
INTO #OurTempTable

SELECT
    OurInitialValue / 2 AS OurFinalValue
FROM #OurTempTable
```

3. Use a subquery. This tends to be more difficult to read than the above. I'm not certain what the advantage is to this - maybe someone in the comments can enlighten me.

```
SELECT
    5 + 5 - 3 AS OurInitialValue
FROM (
    SELECT
        OurInitialValue / 2 AS OurFinalValue
) OurSubquery
```

4. Embed your calculations. *opinion warning* This is really sloppy, and not a great approach as you end up having to duplicate code, and can easily throw columns out-of-sync if you update the calculation in one location and not the other.

```
SELECT
    5 + 5 - 3 AS OurInitialValue
    , (5 + 5 - 3) / 2 AS OurFinalValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use one column to create another column in the same way that you are attempting. You have 2 options:

1. Do the full calculation (as @forpas has mentioned in the comments above)
2. Use a temp table or table variable to store the data, this way you can get the first 5 columns, and then you can add the last column or you can select from the temp table and do the last column calculations from there.

Comment: _"You can't use one column to create another column"_ That's wrong. `Snoozed` is an alias not a column name, and you can use a column to create another one in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use an alias as a column reference in the same query. The correct script is:

```
SELECT 
    pu.ID Id, pu.Name Name,
    COUNT(*) LeadCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Working' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Working,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Uninterested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Uninterested,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Converted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Converted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+100 AS Snoozed
FROM
    Prospects p
INNER JOIN 
    ProspectsUsers pu on p.OwnerId = pu.SalesForceId
WHERE 
    p.Store = '108'
GROUP BY 
    pu.Name, pu.Id
ORDER BY 
    Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column alias in the same select. The column alias do not precedence / sequence; they are all created after the eval of the select result, just before group by and order by.

You must repeat code :

```
SELECT 
    pu.ID Id,pu.Name Name,
    COUNT(*) LeadCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Working' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Working,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Uninterested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Uninterested,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Converted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Converted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Snoozed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 100 AS Test
FROM 
    Prospects p
INNER JOIN 
    ProspectsUsers pu on p.OwnerId = pu.SalesForceId
WHERE 
    p.Store = '108'
GROUP BY 
    pu.Name, pu.Id
ORDER BY    
    Name
```

If you don't want to repeat the code, use a subquery

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, LeadCount, Working, Uninterested,Converted, Snoozed, Snoozed +100 AS test  
FROM
    (SELECT 
          pu.ID Id,pu.Name Name,
            COUNT(*) LeadCount, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Working' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Working,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Uninterested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Uninterested,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Converted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Converted,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SnoozedId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Snoozed

      FROM Prospects p
      INNER JOIN ProspectsUsers pu on p.OwnerId = pu.SalesForceId
      WHERE p.Store = '108'
      GROUP BY pu.Name, pu.Id) t 
   ORDER BY Name
```

or a view